# SQL Inner Queries- Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: java, mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT cmt.topic_id,ctt.description AS topic_name,cmrt.room_id,cmrt.family_id, crt.title AS room_name, ft.family_identifier AS family_name, upt.gender, cmt.postedby_userid, cmt.member_id, 
ut.picture_filename AS senderImage, 
ut.croppedpicture_filename AS senderCroppedImage, 
cmt.image AS imageUrl , 
cmt.message AS caption, 
cmrt.user_id, 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `conversation_messages_tbl` a ,`conversation_msgreadstatus_tbl` b WHERE a.`message_id` = b.`message_id`
AND a.`topic_id` = b.`topic_id` AND  b.`is_read`= 0 AND b.`user_id`!= 27 GROUP BY b.`user_id`) countn
FROM conversation_messages_tbl cmt, 
conversation_topics_tbl ctt , 
conversation_msgreadstatus_tbl cmrt, 
conversation_rooms_tbl crt, family_tbl ft, 
user_profileinformation_tbl upt, 
user_tbl ut 
WHERE ctt.topic_id=cmt.topic_id AND cmrt.message_id=cmt.message_id
AND upt.user_id=cmt.postedby_userid AND crt.room_id=cmrt.room_id AND ft.family_id=crt.family_id 
AND ut.user_id=cmt.postedby_userid AND cmt.message_id=202 GROUP BY cmrt.user_id;
```

I'm getting the error message saying 
Error Code: 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row

Solutions ??

Comment: Don't run subqueries that return more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sub query will return multiple rows, because you have used `GROUP BY b.user_id` and there is not condition between your query and sub query.

If I am thinking in correct way, `cmrt.user_id` is equals to `b.user_id`, you can add a condition to your sub query like the following:

```
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `conversation_messages_tbl` a   
`conversation_msgreadstatus_tbl` b WHERE a.`message_id` = b.`message_id`
AND a.`topic_id` = b.`topic_id` AND  b.`is_read`= 0 AND b.`user_id`!= 27 
b.`user_id`=cmrt.user_id) countn
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query

```
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `conversation_messages_tbl` a ,`conversation_msgreadstatus_tbl` b WHERE a.`message_id` = b.`message_id` AND a.`topic_id` = b.`topic_id` AND  b.`is_read`= 0 AND b.`user_id`!= 27 GROUP BY b.`user_id`) countn
```

may return more than 1 row, as it will return a count for each distinct user_id different from 27 (because of group by).